# `get_meta_tags` didn't read og:image

Tags: php, get-meta-tags

I want to read the `og:image` meta tag from a URL. I want to use `get_meta_tags`, but it doesn't return the value for this meta tag.

What is the reason for this and how can I solve it?

**Code**

```
<?php
$tags = get_meta_tags('https://stackoverflow.com/');
?>
<pre>
    <?php
        print_r($tags);
    ?>
</pre>
```

**HTML Input**

```
 <meta property="og:type" content= "website" />
 <meta property="og:url" content="https://stackoverflow.com/"/>
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="Stack Overflow" />
 <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" />
 <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"/>
 <meta name="twitter:domain" content="stackoverflow.com"/>
 <meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="title name" content="Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, &amp; Build Careers" />
 <meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="Stack Overflow | The World’s Largest Online Community for Developers" />
```

**Result**

```
   Array
(
    [description] => Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers to learn, share​ ​their programming ​knowledge, and build their careers.
    [viewport] => width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0
    [twitter:card] => summary
    [twitter:domain] => stackoverflow.com
    [twitter:title] => Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers
    [twitter:description] => Stack Overflow | The World’s Largest Online Community for Developers
)
```

Comment: @Batteredburrito This isn't a duplicate question. I asked why `get_meta_tags` didn't read og:image.... I don't want to use `file_get_contains`

Comment: @yivi It is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work.

[`get_meta_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php) uses the `name` attribute of the meta tags to populate the array keys.

If you check the HTML of the page you are trying to get this values from, you'll see this:

```
 <meta property="og:type" content= "website" />
 <meta property="og:url" content="https://stackoverflow.com/"/>
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="Stack Overflow" />
 <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" />
```

As you can see, none of those tags have a `name` attribute, so it's impossible for the function to assign those values to any key.

You will have to use a different method to get these meta tags.